# Color for [favorite] tags questions on new SO design needs to be stronger

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On many screens (especially those with bad viewing angles) the color used in the new SO design of questions tagged with a [favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favorite) tag can be very weak and hard to see.

I think it would be a very good idea to have it a little stronger, to make them stand out a little bit more on a variety of screens.

Comment: Same goes for visited vs non-visited links... it's all a bit washed out. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Absolutely. Love the design, it just needs a few tweaks.

Comment: And visited vs non-visited is really annoying, as during quick googling some topic I often open dozens of similar questions, and understanding if I visit some links (often hidden in words like 'this', 'here' etc) shown in answers is vital.

Comment: Everyone will need some time to get used to the new design. Initially I didn't like the black header when it was introduces, but I'm completely fine with it now.

Comment: @kocko Very true indeed, people are very reticent to change, but I genuinely can't tell the difference between a visited and non-visited link on my (admittedly poor but purposely so) laptop screen.

Comment: In addition, I think it should match the "Hot Meta Posts" color. "Favorite Tags" question color has (probably) some more blue, difference is subtle but slightly annoying.

Comment: When I set my favorite tags first time, I did know what is the benefit from this since my screen was too bad to show this tiny color difference.

Comment: I just went to ask this question and found it has already been flagged. The new shading for questions with my favorite tags are almost impossible to see on my Toshiba laptop when viewed at any angle other than straight-on (where nobody sets a laptop display for normal reading). At angles as slight as 10-15 degrees off perpendicular, the shading almost disappears. Can you add more saturation to the color to make it more visible, please...

Comment: Just a followup to see if this is being worked, of all the changes, this one really needs to be addressed. For whatever reason, browsing the question list with a nearly imperceptible difference between favorite tagged/non-tagged questions puts a real strain on the eyes. The shading should be similar to the `Hot Meta Posts` box at the top-right. That in unobtrusive and instantly distinguishable. Thanks.