# Stronger shade for highlighted questions of favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

Something that I have been noticing lately is that the shade in which Questions asked in my favorite tags are highlighted has been lightened a bit. For example, this screenshot:

[image]

Now, `iPhone`, `swift`, `ipad`, `ios` are in my favorite tags but `jmeter` and `okhttp`, `http2` are not. I can notice slight highlight on ios related questions but it is somehow less visible than previously (I actually had to use Digital color meter app to distinguish between the two).

I don't know if it is relevant or even has an impact on the design visibility but I am color blind as well so it might be that it looks fine to most of the community members but it doesn't to me at least.

I believe previously the favorite tags' questions were highlighted in RGB (254, 247,220). Now they are highlighted in (255,250,236) which is much closer to white which makes them hard to spot in a whole page of questions.

There are two similar feature requests posts, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283674/color-for-favorite-tags-questions-on-new-so-design-needs-to-be-stronger) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283871/darker-color-for-favorite-tags). Despite getting good response from community there is still no response on them after almost a year so I thought maybe I should raise this issue again as this is a huge problem especially for people with vision defects such as me.

Can we please make the highlight shade a bit stronger to help with visibility?

Please let me know if I should have stuck to bumping up the previous posts in this regard rather than making a new post about it. I will gladly take it down.

Comment: I agree. The lighter shade is not helping visibility, although I am not color blind, I still don't like the current shade.

Comment: I'd vote to make the highlight color as light as the normal background, i.e. the I want an option to remove the highlighting.

Comment: FYI, [already asked a couple of days ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321739/4151918).

Comment: Are you using the new-nav beta? It might help to create tabs for specific tags which would stop those non-favorite tag questions from even appearing. You'd end up with a consistent background and only see your favorite-tagged questions.

Comment: @PetahChristian No I don't think I am using the new-nav beta.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO just [lightened the favorite tags background last week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321414/could-the-new-green-color-for-accepted-unaccepted-questions-be-tweaked-against-y) so it wouldn't clash with the new green.

SO tweaked both the new green (so it wasn't as vivid) and the background (to avoid any optical illusions due to the two saturated colors). This was a reasonable compromise, and most seem to be ok with the final result.

[Since the new color changes were important in reducing the size of the CSS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321419/4151918), an better solution at this point may be to employ a user script to customize any colors to your own individual requirements.

**With regard to color blindness:**

I don't know if it's possible to come up with a palette of colors which would be distinguishable for everyone, yet also be visually effective and pleasing, but it's something the designers have likely considered.

If the site colors do pose an issue due to color blindness, you should make a specific post about that, showing how the site's colors would appear for specific types of color blindness.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You might want to post the same answer on the other two answer-less posts that I have linked in my post.

Comment: If there are any feature requests for user customizable color, I'd certainly upvote it as well. As for colorblindness, I am not sure if that's really having an impact on visibility nor do I know how do they appear to any normal person. I just know that it is very hard for me to distinguish the colors (Had to check RGB to know the difference).